# How can I wrap two chosen elements with a div using PHP's DOMDocument?

Tags: php, domdocument

I have selected 2 elements (siblings) using PHP's DOMDocument (with a little help of DOMXPath).

```
$dom = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');

$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = FALSE;

$dom->loadHTML($content);

$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

$query = '//h3[text() = "Amenities"]';

$title = $xpath->query($query)->item(0);

$list = $title->nextSibling;
```

This gets me the `h3` title (`$title`) and the `ul` list (`$list`).

I want to wrap them with a `div`, and add an `id`.

I'm sure I can do the `id` part, but I'm not sure how to wrap these elements in DOMDocument.

Would I?

1. Create new `div` element
2. Clone elements (`h3` and `ul`) and insert them as children of newly created `div`
3. Remove old elements (original `h3` and `ul`)

Is there a more straightforward way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`appendChild()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/domnode.appendchild.php) method to move an existing node. So:

- Create a new div
- Use appendChild on the new div to make your chosen elements a child of this div