# How to wrap element with another element with php

Tags: php, domdocument

I am pretty new to php domdocument and I am trying to wrap the html with a `<a>` tag when there is a span tag.

My html is like

```
text….<span>test here.</span>…another text here
```

I want to wrap them with php domdocument.

```
  $dom = new DomDocument();
  $dom->loadHTML($html);

        $xpath=new DOMXpath($dom);
        $result = $xpath->query('//span');

              if($result->length > 0){
                 $strong=$dom->createElement('a');
                 //I am not sure what to do next……..

              }
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Is this all the HTML? Can it include many span elements or just one?

Comment: this is just an example. I have many html and many of them have span tag

Answer (score -1):

If I am understanding what you are trying to do, this post might help you: [How can I wrap two chosen elements with a div using PHP's DOMDocument?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5062655/how-can-i-wrap-two-chosen-elements-with-a-div-using-phps-domdocument)

From what I can tell, you need to use `appendChild()` to make `$result` a child of `$strong`. That should look something like:

```
$strong->appendChild($result);
```